# Is it possible to share files over multiple protocols?

Tags: linux, network-shares, nfs, smb

If you have a (linux) server, is it possible to share certain files and folders using more than one protocol?
For example, sharing a file over SMB and NFS.
If it is possible, is this recommended?
Or should a single protocol be used to avoid conflicts, CPU overhead or transfer speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely possible, yes. You could share a file via `SMB`, `NFS`, `FTP` and `HTTP` at the same time. There will be processing overhead depending on the size of the file(s) if the same file is requested multiple times, but there are no problems to do so.
It entirely depends on the usecase.